# Add ui:include and ui:param to binding

Tags: jsf, binding, facelets

I have a UIComponent that is binded to a backing bean. I'd like to add a child to the component that corresponds to the ui:include tag and ui:param 
here 's an example of what want to do :

```
<p:tab>      
  <ui:include src="tpl.xhtml" >
   <ui:param name="beanName" value="#{tableBean}" />
   </ui:include>
 </p:tab>
```

I want to create this in my backing bean like:

thanks to this fourm and its active comunity i found  the way to add the include with

```
    FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
        faceletContext.includeFacelet(tab, "tpl.xhtml");
```

However I cant find a way specify the params

Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved it , 
here 's how :
 
       FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
    faceletContext.includeFacelet(t, "tpl.xhtml");
    faceletContext.setAttribute("beanName", tableBean);

where tableBean is a property in my backing Bean .

Comment: This is a good question I don't think the answer is very complete. I think the scope of the attribute when set with faceletContext.setAttribute will not be the same as the example xhtml.   For example, you could not use this method in a loop with different tableBean instances. I would like to know how to accomplish this correctly.